# Разобрать ответ от JSON php

Tags: php, массивы, json

ВОт приходит вот такой вот ответ от JSON:

```html
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 440233585 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f4/HFuPadOTw6g.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f5/jHz6k1Dd-eA.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f3/b9_PE-4lt28.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f6/ZhtP8I_sp14.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f7/LicLSpZOmIE.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447260 [post_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [pid] => 440233719 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da03/eR4Y1nXKxSg.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da04/tYJ0P_V1N-Q.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da02/dQ9Hm9MA_w8.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da05/rUTUZHqwI-w.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da06/AhFkbBmmQDw.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447300 [post_id] => 3 ) )
```

Подскажите, как из него достать значение pid и owner id , из первой строки, остальные pid мне не нужны

Answer (score 3):

Если только первого то так:

```html
$k = Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 440233585 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f4/HFuPadOTw6g.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f5/jHz6k1Dd-eA.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f3/b9_PE-4lt28.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f6/ZhtP8I_sp14.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f7/LicLSpZOmIE.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447260 [post_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [pid] => 440233719 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da03/eR4Y1nXKxSg.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da04/tYJ0P_V1N-Q.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da02/dQ9Hm9MA_w8.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da05/rUTUZHqwI-w.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da06/AhFkbBmmQDw.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447300 [post_id] => 3 ) );

$pid = $k[0]['pid'];
$owner_id = $k[0]['owner_id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON разбирается с помощью http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php но у вас в примере уже раскодированный ответ т.к. в json фигурные скобки должны быть а так Dmitriy Kondratiuk верно написал:

```
$pid = $k[0]['pid'];
$owner_id = $k[0]['owner_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше уж так

```
$k = Array ( [0] => Array ( [pid] => 440233585 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f4/HFuPadOTw6g.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f5/jHz6k1Dd-eA.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f3/b9_PE-4lt28.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f6/ZhtP8I_sp14.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/d9f7/LicLSpZOmIE.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447260 [post_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [pid] => 440233719 [aid] => -6 [owner_id] => 393361468 [src] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da03/eR4Y1nXKxSg.jpg [src_big] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da04/tYJ0P_V1N-Q.jpg [src_small] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da02/dQ9Hm9MA_w8.jpg [src_xbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da05/rUTUZHqwI-w.jpg [src_xxbig] => https://pp.vk.me/c836234/v836234468/da06/AhFkbBmmQDw.jpg [width] => 1024 [height] => 768 [text] => [created] => 1478447300 [post_id] => 3 ) );

foreach($k AS $value) {
   $pid = $value['pid'];
}
```